# Naming a VLAN with a space in name

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-commands, command

I am supposed to name 2 vlans, VLAN 10, and VLAN 20.

When I type

```
Switch(config-vlan)#Name VLAN 10
                          ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Could I get any help please.

Comment: You cannot use blank spaces, you need to use `name VLAN_10` or `name VLAN-10` etc.

Comment: What equipment are you working on? I just tried on a Catalyst 3560CX and that worked without a problem. Also the IOS version would be interesting to know.

Comment: Why on earth would you name VLAN 10 as "VLAN 10"? Normally, you want to name a VLAN for its use, such as naming VLAN 10 something like "Printers" or whatever purpose it serves. Some people name a VLAN for the floor it serves, or something else descriptive. You already know that VLAN 10 is VLAN 10, and you do not need to name it that way.

Comment: On some devices this works by using quotes `name "VLAN 10"` - but as Ron has noted, that name is useless.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Just to leave it here: IOS 15.0 does not allow spaces, but 15.2 does allow.

Answer (score 1):

Use an underscore instead. ;)

Spaces aren't usually allowed in the names of interfaces.

Sometimes you can name with a space if you use Quotes "VLAN 10" but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

When configuring a VLAN's it's recommended by Cisco to use underscores instead of spaces.

Hence the correct configuration would be:

```
Switch(config-vlan)#name VLAN_10
```

and

```
Switch(config-vlan)#name VLAN_20
```